# SQL Server 2014 Alias Call Issue - Cannot used Local Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

The code below is meant to clean up some null values in a dataset. It needs to be compatible with Tableau so I am unable to use declared variables, and I have gotten pushback/do not have authorization to create a stored procedure.

I am attempting (and after research realizing SQL doesn't operate this way) to reference an Alias which utilizes a case statement in a second Alias case statement.

The error that pops is "`Invalid Column Name 'Store`' " in the Segment Alias. The location of where the field shows as invalid is italicized and bold.

Any help or thoughts on a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @Store_Type nvarchar(30);

select c.id, 
c.name, 
e.type,
Store_Type = 
CASE WHEN e.type IS NOT NULL THEN e.type 
ELSE (
    CASE 
    WHEN c.id = '1' THEN ('Foo')
    WHEN c.id = '2' THEN ('Bar')
    WHEN c.id = '3' THEN ('Baz')
    WHEN c.name like 'Woo%' THEN ('Woot')
    WHEN c.id = '4' THEN ('Zoot')
    ELSE 'Zed'
    END)
    END,
b.segment,
Segment_Name = 
    CASE
    WHEN (b.segment IS NOT NULL OR e.type = @Store_Type) THEN b.segment
    WHEN b.segment IS NULL and e.type ='A' THEN 'AAA'
    WHEN b.segment IS NULL and e.type ='B' THEN 'BBB'
    WHEN b.segment IS NULL and e.type ='C' THEN 'CCC'
    WHEN b.segment IS NULL and e.type ='D' THEN 'DDD'

 ELSE 'ZZZ'
END,

c.city, 
C.state, 
c.company, 
c.group, 
convert(date, a.timestamp) as date, 
d.approvalamount, 
convert(date,metacreatets) as approval_date

FROM stores c

JOINS GO HERE
```

Comment: Is that triple asterisk valid SQL in SQL Server? Never seen that before.

Comment: I think that you are attempting to update two columns, correct?  Or something else?  Is it important to update them separately, or can this be done at the same time?

Comment: Just copy-paste first expression .

Comment: Good catch Jacob, that was for formatting purposes before I had set the code flag and I edited it out now.

Comment: what are you trying to say with `a.store=store` ?

Comment: Saying `a.store=store` is affecting the cleaning of the null values. Basically it is saying if the stored variable in the pre-existing table matches the `store` value referenced above, then print `c.segment`

If I remove that code it does not work as intended.

Comment: Why don't you just show the full query?

Comment: I've added something more representative of the actual code. It is currently using a declared variable for Store_Type in order to call a check during the Segment_Name alias action.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic here. We know that, if `e.type` is not null then `Store_Type` is equal to `e.type`. So when in the second case we do `e.type = store_type`, isn't this just the same as asserting again that `e.type is not null`?

Comment: Damien, that's half of my problem here. Some of the records are complete, and some are half-complete. 

That check is to make sure that if the segment is not null, or the store type matches the scrubbed store type, then it should use that segment name.

Any changes I have made to the code have caused it to not work as intended. Especially when I try to remove my declared variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When connecting Tableau with a SQL Server database connection, there is a difference between utilizing the **'Custom SQL Query'** to enter the SQL code and the **'Initial SQL...'**

This option is available by right clicking on the **Server Name under the Connections label** on the Data Source tab.

**'Initial SQL...'** requires some getting used to, but it does allow Tableau users connecting with at least MSSQL Server to utilize **declared variables, temp tables, and common table expressions.**

This ultimately was the path of least resistance to get the desired result. Another alternative would be to work with IT colleagues to set up a stored procedure, but that is more than a few extra steps for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a CTE for this? I haven't used tableau so am unaware of the exact details, but this seems like something that can be done using a CTE

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN A.[Store] IS NOT NULL --Case statement is executed in order,i.e., the next statement gets executed only when previous one is not met
                THEN A.[store]
            WHEN B.ID = '1'
                THEN ('Foo')
            WHEN B.[ID] = '2'
                THEN ('Bar')
            ELSE 'Baz'
            END AS [Store]
    FROM A
        ,B --I am guessing a join condition goes here
    )
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN C.[Segment] IS NOT NULL
            OR A.[Store] = @Store --I am assumming Store is a variable in your original command
            THEN c.segment
        ELSE (
                CASE 
                    WHEN c.segment IS NULL
                        AND type = 'Doo'
                        THEN 'Dadz'
                    WHEN a.store = 'Foo'
                        THEN 'Bar'
                    ELSE 'Baz'
                    END
                )
        END
FROM C
    ,CTE AS A
```